# React component do not gets updated after changing the the state in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm working on a react component that render a table with some data coming down from an API on the server as follows:

```js
var ModulesTable = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            modules: ""
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {

        var get = $.get("/api/Modules/GetModules")
            .done(function (results) {

                if (results != null) {
                    var rows = results.map((module) => {

                        var statusImg;
                        if (module.IsActive)
                            statusImg = <a><i className="ti-check"></i></a>;

                        return
                        (<tr>
                            <td>{module.ModuleId}</td>
                            <td>{module.ModuleName}</td>
                            <td>{statusImg}</td>
                        </tr>);
                    }
                    );
                    this.setState({
                        modules: rows
                    });
                }
            }
                .bind(this))
            .fail(function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });

    },
    render: function () {
        return (<table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Used</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.state.modules}
            </tbody>
        </table>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ModulesTable />,
    document.getElementById("tableContainer"));
```

The problem is the component is not gets updated with the data returned from the API and the console show no signs of any error plus the API is working fine. 
I suspect that the problem with setState probably. 
what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the output of console.log(results) in .done callback function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri the api return an array of objects [{"Id":1,"ModuleId":1,"ModuleName":"Contracts Management","IsActive":true,"CreatedDate":"2018-04-03T00:00:00"},{"Id":2,"ModuleId":2,"ModuleName":"Assets Management","IsActive":true,"CreatedDate":"2018-04-03T00:00:00"}]

Comment: you have whitespace in `.bind(this)` . try removing it. Also can you check the updated state in setState callback

Comment: sorry that is not working either

Comment: are you getting any warning in the console.? As you said you are not getting any error message, I boubt u must be getting a warring as You missed to add `key` attr in `<tr>`. so may u are never inside the loop

Comment: which version of react are you using

Comment: @ved  Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace between tags on each line of your source code. See ModulesTable > tbody > #text.

Comment: This seem unnecessarily complicated. Simplify the jquery callback, and use a dumb component for table rows, instead of putting render logic inside a jquery callback inside componentDidMount.

Comment: So, as per warring, DOM is not valid. So you are not able to get updated view.

Comment: @HåkenLid can you post a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by getting rid of map function and use the regular for loop fixed my problem as following :

```
componentDidMount: function () {

        var get = $.get("/api/Modules/GetModules")
            .done(function (results) {
                if (results != null) {

                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var module = results[i];

                        if (module.IsActive) {

                            rows.push(
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{module.ModuleId}</td>
                                    <td>{module.ModuleName}</td>
                                    <td><a><i className="ti-check"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        }

                        else {
                            rows.push(
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{module.ModuleId}</td>
                                    <td>{module.ModuleName}</td>
                                    <td><a><i className="ti-close"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        }

                    }

                    this.setState({
                        modules: rows
                    });

                    console.log(rows);
                }
            }.bind(this))
            .fail(function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` does not work with `jQuery xhr callbacks`. Just try this instead

```
    const self = this;
    var get = $.get("/api/Modules/GetModules")
        .done(function (results) {

            if (results != null) {
                var rows = results.map((module) => {

                    var statusImg;
                    if (module.IsActive)
                        statusImg = <a><i className="ti-check"></i></a>;

                    return
                    (<tr>
                        <td>{module.ModuleId}</td>
                        <td>{module.ModuleName}</td>
                        <td>{statusImg}</td>
                    </tr>);
                }
                );
                self.setState({
                    modules: rows
                });
            }
        }
            .bind(this))
        .fail(function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
```

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain Did you try `console.log(rows)`...? Does it return any something?

Comment: Ahmed  console.log(rows) shows [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] strange

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain better make a simple `fiddle` that would better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.modules` instead of `modules`, see demo @ https://jsfiddle.net/wv3yopo0/2674/